# Cannot establish connect between IBM Content Navigator to Content Platform

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, ibm-content-navigator, content-platform-engine

I am deploying IBM Content Platform Engine (CPE) and IBM COntent Navigator (ICN)
the CPE is deployed into Websphere 1 at *192.168.1.16*
the ICN is deployed into Websphere 2 at *192.168.1.17*

I browser to *http://192.168.1.17:9080/navigator* to add new repository but I cannot with the exception ": ***FNRCA0031E: API_UNABLE_TO_USE_CONNECTION: The URI for server communication cannot be determined from the connection object ConnectionImpl@0x3939b86d URI=iiop://192.168.1.16:2809/Filenet/Engine tenant=null Parameters={}.***"

My input URL info:*iiop://192.168.1.16:9810/Filenet/Engine*

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  You're better off posting to http://serverfault.com.  IN ANY CASE: 1) Make sure you can access CPE (http://192.168.1.16:9080/FileNet/Engine), then 2) Make sure ICN is installe and running correctly (http://192.168.1.17:9080/navigator/Ping).  Consider re-running ICN Config mgr and re-deploying if CPE is OK but you still can't connect.

Comment: @dientmUET, did you resolve this? I'm in the same situation